# How to make the best use of limited teleportation?

Tags: magic, super-powers, teleportation

People in a modern setting have started gaining mysterious powers (you know how this goes), but they're pretty rare and they all have significant limitations.  Our protagonist has the particularly rare ability to teleport (he's the only one with such a power as far as we're aware), but the downside is that he's limited to teleporting what he thinks of as his body.  This means no other people, no tools and no clothing.

He can teleport to anywhere that he can picture well (having been there) or to anywhere with sufficiently detailed photographs (Google Street View suffices.)  Standard hand-waving applies to prevent intersecting solid objects or other people upon arrival, though he doesn't have any remote viewing, so he isn't sure what he'll be jumping into.  It requires a bit of concentration and time (maybe a few minutes), so it's not something he can use to jump around the room in a fight.

In other settings of this type, teleportation is often used productively to transport others, but that's not an option here.  Given the limitations and how vulnerable his power leaves him upon arrival, how can he leverage this ability to good advantage?

Comment: For starters, he's the perfect thief. *"Macavity, Macavity, there's no one like Macavity, he's broken every human law, he breaks the law of gravity. His powers of levitation would make a fakir stare, and when you reach the scene of crime—Macavity's not there! You may seek him in the basement, you may look up in the air—but I tell you once and once again, Macavity's not there!"* (T S Eliot, *Macavity: The Mystery Cat*)

Comment: @AlexP But how can he steal things when he can't take the loot with him?  Sure, he can teleport into a bank vault if he gets a picture of it, but then he'd have to find a way to walk out of it.

Comment: As written this doesn't seem to be about worldbuildig. You've already created your rules of teleportation and are now asking what would somebody do. Questions asking "What would someone do?" are often closed as too story based.

Comment: He doesn't teleport with the loot. He teleports into the house to be burgled, takes the loot and gives it to an accomplice, then teleports back to his hotel room in Honolulu. When the police identifies him he rightfully points out that he was booked in a hotel in Honolulu ten thousand miles away.

Comment: How would this affect, say, bodypaint

Comment: @Paul TIKI, the current concept is that it's based on his psychological sense of self, so I'm thinking bodypaint probably wouldn't work, but a tattoo might, since that has a sense of 'altering' the body more permanently.

Comment: OK, cool.  That is an interesting twist, using a sense of self.  I like it

Comment: @DanBryant Okay so following this logic, if he put a couple hundred hours into it, he could pretty much carry anything as his standard set of gear.  Wearing the same outfit, always strapping on a gun, etc would alter his perception of self.  Pretty much anything he has on him that he forgets is there or feels wrong if missing (phone, wallet, keys) counts.  For example, I feel naked without my watch. Also I would just go to Vegas and work out some weird Magic / Erotic show. Maybe with a gag about a never ending line of men running into a closet to have sex with [insert name]'s mom.

Comment: For the close voters, I see this as world-building as the OP is looking for ways to resolve something in the world he built from being too broken.  As it stands, the world and premise is kinda broken and the OP is looking for a way to smooth out a rough edge on a concept of teleportation limited by sense of self.  Dan, can you re-word, maybe to reflect this if I'm on track.  I already voted to re-open

Comment: @PaulTIKI, I may take some time later to see if I can rephrase in a more world-oriented way.  It's unfortunate that there isn't a 'character building' site to provide a venue for interesting character-decision-focused questions.

Comment: If interested in allowing the person to teleport others, have the teleportor learn about entanglement and proceed to entangle with whomever helps the plot. Once entangled, their sense of self will include these other folks. Make it irreversible or non-compartable, and there exists another twist where they lose the ability to teleport just as their original single body.

Comment: He can learn by stumbling onto Physics SE questions/answers like this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103359/double-double-slit-experiment

Comment: @DanBryant Character Building topics might be something we can take over to Meta for discussion.  I think it would be worthy of that, given that characters are part of, and can certainly influence our perception of the world being created

Comment: Could he swallow something and transport it inside him?  Or in his mouth?

Comment: How to make best use?  Meditation.  With meditation and ritualization, he can extend that sense-of-self to his "common things" - for example, people are clothed in most self-images, or feel something missing when without things they carry everywhere.  More specifically he is already teleporting stuff that isn't *his body*, like the contents of his digestive system, or illnesses or drugs, or prosthetics, or probably anything planted under his skin.  He just needs to trick himself into thinking his power will let him take <whatever> and he can, since the limitation is explicitly psychological.

Comment: Define body.  Could he make a living teleporting up to the ISS to urinate?  Bringing mass to space costs thousands of dollars a pound, I would think purification would be cheaper than bringing up water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spying and Assasination.

Obviously, these are going to take a lot of prep, and if he decides to kill people for money, tons of hand to hand combat training.

for the spying, Since he can't teleport stuff with him, the only thing he could bring out would be information.  So he jumps in, listens at the door or rifles through drawers, then jumps out.  He's going to have a hard time getting started, but with a reputation he could make money as a professional fly on the wall.

Assassination is slightly different.  He would have to train extensively to kill with bare hands.  Also, he'd need stealth skills. After that it would be a matter of scouting, setting up an alibi, then popping in, killing someone, and popping back out.

Keep in mind that even these two are going to require a lot of prep to pull off.  Even getting past the first few layers of security doesn't mean you get through all of them.  Also, you arrive naked.  If you want to wear clothes during the caper, you have to store them ahead of time.  If you want to be camouflaged upon arrival, you have to tattoo...everything!  OUCH!

Also keep in mind that you will be leaving behind forensic evidence, like sweat, hand, and footprints, so maybe measures against this would be a good idea.  That means more preparation, salting the scene ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a great ability for someone who gets in trouble with the law. The person gets arrested and thrown in the back of the squad car. Cop does some other stuff. When the cop checks on his prisoner, he finds him gone, and only his clothes remain.

Eventually, this character would set up "safe houses" or places where he or she would have a change of clothes and whatever was needed to get by. Think Jason Bourne in the Bourne movies, where he would find lock-boxes randomly with passports and cash.

For a character with a more legitimate profession, try a private detective. Got a cheating spouse? He can teleport over and surprise that person in the nude. Other kinda legit professions would be information courier or spy.

Also, if this character is able to teleport anything he swallows (which he could consider part of himself), he would make an excellent drug mule.

Answer (score 0):

**Vegas Baby**

This skill set would be useful to magicians / escape artists. The fact that you are nude can be incorporated into the act.

Act 1: Invite an attractive female from the audience (preferably one with a date) up on stage. Wheel a standing box / closet out. Tell the audience that the two of you are just going to make yourself comfortable (wink at audience). Enter closet. Constantly teleport side stage, grab trench coat and giant prosthetic penis (like 3 feet long). Rush on stage and into the closet (prosthetic waving in the wind). Continue 20x.

Act 2: Create **Certain Death Machine X** place on stage and make a big deal about entering it.  Teleport naked to a random table in the audience. Tap person at table on shoulder and ask "How you doing."

Act 3: You are now a weird sexy / silly magician. The audience will never suspect when you teleport to the Kremlin and strangle Putin. You were really working for the CIA all along.